# Fully plot axes in matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm using `GeoPandas` to plot a `shapely` geometry with `matplotlib`. the resulting image has many white spaces surrounding the map. It does not seem that `plt.tight_layout` do the job.

```
# producing a map!

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this module is for basemap
import contextily as ctx 

# gdf is like Pandas DataFrame, but with a column of Shapely Geometry
# we can do pandas DataFrame methods for gdf
gdf = gpd.read_file("the data.shp")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gdf[gdf.n == 0].plot(column = "JF", ax=ax, cmap="RdYlGn_r")
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=gdf.crs.to_string(), source=ctx.providers.CartoDB.DarkMatter)

ax.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("imgs/" + str(n)+".png", dpi=250)
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

the code produces this image. I fill the background with red using Ms. Paint. As illustrated, there are so many red fills! the map is too small.
[image]

---

I'm not sure about the keywords and nomenclature to be used. 
my question is, how to fully plot the map in the figure like this image below? I cropped the image using ms paint.

[image]

Comment: try adding the `bbox_inches="tight"` parameter to your call to `savefig`

Comment: thank you, it reduces significantly! there are still white spaces, but it is enough.